# 3-way tabulation in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataset that looks like

```
| ID | Category | Failure |
|----+----------+---------|
|  1 | a        | 0       |
|  1 | b        | 0       |
|  1 | b        | 0       |
|  1 | a        | 0       |
|  1 | c        | 0       |
|  1 | d        | 0       |
|  1 | c        | 0       |
|  1 | failure  | 1       |
|  2 | c        | 0       |
|  2 | d        | 0       |
|  2 | d        | 0       |
|  2 | b        | 0       |
```

This is data where each ID potentially ends in a failure event, through an intermediate sequence of events `{a, b, c, d}`. I want to be able to count the number of IDs for which each of those intermediate events occur by failure event.

So, I would like a table of the form

```
|            | a | b | c | d |
|------------+---+---+---+---|
| Failure    | 4 | 5 | 6 | 2 |
| No failure | 9 | 8 | 6 | 9 |
```

where, for example, the number 4 indicates that in 4 of the IDs where `a` occurred ended in failure.

How would I go about doing this in R?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` for example:

```
dat <- data.frame(categ=sample(letters[1:4],20,rep=T),
                  failure=sample(c(0,1),20,rep=T))

res <- table(dat$failure,dat$categ)
rownames(res) <- c('Failure','No failure')
res
           a b c d
Failure    3 2 2 1
No failure 1 2 4 5
```

you can plot it using `barplot`:

```
barplot(res)
```

[image]

**EDIT** to get this by ID, you can use `by` for example:

```
  dat <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,9),rep(2,11)),categ=sample(letters[1:4],20,rep=T),
               failure=sample(c(0,1),20,rep=T))
 by(dat,dat$ID,function(x)table(x$failure,x$categ))
dat$ID: 1

    a b c d
  0 1 2 1 3
  1 1 1 0 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$ID: 2

    a b c d
  0 1 2 3 0
  1 1 3 1 0
```

**EDIT** using **tapply**

Another way to get this is using `tapply`

```
  with(dat,tapply(categ,list(failure,categ,ID),length))
```

Comment: `categ` also includes the failure indicator as a possible value, how can I adjust for that?